# Make n numbers equal

Tags: algorithms, constructive-mathematics

Given $n$ rational numbers. Every time you can delete $2$ numbers, and add 2 numbers which are equal to $\frac{a+b}{2}$ (assume the number you delete is $a$ and $b$). How to judge whether it is possible to make these $n$ numbers equal in finite steps? If possible, how to construct it?

Comment: if $n=2^k$, then we can easily construct an answer using divide-and-conquer. Let the average number of the $n$ numbers is $x$. A sufficient condition is if we can divide these $n$ numbers into several groups and for each group, its average number is equal to $x$ and its size is power of 2.

Comment: If $n=3$ and there are no two numbers whose average is the third, it is impossible.

Comment: Yeah, $\{0,0,1\}$ was the basic counterexample I had come up with. The problem seems to be invariant under scaling and shifting, so you can WLOG have integers with no common factor. And then you can only get powers of two in the denominator after that.